# Unable to view the contents of the dlls "System.Runtime", "System.Resources.ResourceManager " and "System.ObjectModel "

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I downloaded the dll's "`System.Runtime", "System.Resources.ResourceManager " and "System.ObjectModel"`  online, and tried to view the contents of these dll's using both the "**Object Browser**" and the "**.NET Reflector Object Browser**" in the Visual Studio 2013. But  I am not able to view the contents of these dlls.

However the content of the other .NET dll's for e.g., "`System.Printing`" (this wasn't downloaded) e.t.c can be viewed. Does anyone have any idea why this is happening? Please help!

Comment: They are reference assemblies, they only contain metadata.  Very little of it, just [TypeForwardedTo] to the real .NET assembly that contains the types.   It is the way that they can hide or alter types that are not usable in a project that targets a limited .NET version (PCL, Store, Phone, Universal, Silverlight, etc).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. As I am new to this concept, could you please break it down a little bit so that I can understand thoroughly.